# non-imperative て ending in a sentence

Tags: verbs

> 佐藤：ところで、前田君、すごいよね。今年も優秀社員に選ばれて、ボーナスもアップだっ　て。うらやましい～。
>
> ワン：前田さんって、完璧ですね。入社してからトラブルを起こしたことなんて、一回もないんじゃないですか。
>
> 佐藤：いや、優秀社員とはいえ、トラブルはあるよ。彼だって最初ワンさんと同じような新人だったから。入社してまだ三年目のときだったかな、彼が担当したプロジェクトが大失敗したことも**あって**ねえ。
>
> ワン：ええ。
>
> 佐藤：そのプロジェクトが大失敗してからというもの、彼はすごく**努力して**ね。朝一番に会社に来たり、自主的にセミナーに行ったり**して**。

Reading this, I was thinking, the typical use of て-form ending a sentence is to show imperative mood, but here is definitely not the case. I suppose 大失敗したこともあって=大失敗したこともある, 彼はすごく努力してね=彼はすごく努力してきたね, セミナーに行ったりして=セミナーに行ったりしている.

If my understanding is correct, then under what situation do Japanese prefer to use "te form" instead of an ordinary form if imperative mood is not intended? Or it is simply a peculiar speaking style?

Answer (score 4):

Often the て form at the end of a sentence gives a feel of continuing (like there is more to say), especially when followed by ね, な or さ. I think the first two cases above fall in this category.

In English rather than using a word for this I think it is more commonly expressed with tone.

However, in the very last case (and perhaps the first as well) in the above text I feel that it is more of a sense of an afterthought or explanation. So the "朝一番に会社に来たり、自主的にセミナーに行ったりして" is more of an example of how he "すごく努力して「いた」".

To give a simpler example:

> 彼は勉強が大好きでね。夜遅くまで勉強したりして。
>
> He really loved studying. He did stuff like studying up until late at night.

In English I would probably prefer use a comma instead of a period between these two sentences, however.